# E se eu quiser enviar e receber um "pacote"?

Tags: c#, socket, tcpclient

Coloquei um mini teste de servidor online e deu tudo certo, o problema é que eu quero enviar inteiros, booleanos, strings, etc... Até agora só sei enviar string, como dar os primeiros passos?
Por enquanto estou usando isso:

```
string dataFromServer = await serverReader.ReadLineAsync(); //Aguardando mensagens
```

Eu gostaria de enviar pacotes com um inteiro indicando o id dele pra eu saber a estruturação e o resto indefinido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ícaro,

Para ler dados que não são strings você não poderá utilizar um StreamReader como no exemplo que você colocou. É possível conter valores também dentro da string, mas isso vai depender da implementação de um protocolo próprio para tal.

Atualmente é possível fazer a leitura de qualquer tipo de dado através de socket utilizo a própria classe Socket e os métodos "Receive, ReceiveFrom, ReceiveMessageFrom" e suas  variantes assíncronas.

Estes métodos recebem como parâmetro um array do tipo byte e retornam um inteiro correspondendo ao número de bytes recebidos.

Utilizada a função e armazenados os bytes você pode utilizar as funções de conversão contidas na classe BitConverter para gerar um dos tipos primitivos implementados pelo .NET Framework.

Segue exemplo (apenas com propósito educacional, código não adequado para ambiente de produção):

```
var listener = new TcpListener(8080);
listener.Start();

while (true)
{
    const int buffer_length = 1024;
    byte[] dados = new byte[buffer_length];

    Socket cliente = listener.AcceptSocket();

    if (!cliente.Connected) continue;

    int recv_length = cliente.Receive(dados, buffer_length, SocketFlags.None);

    if(recv_length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            Int32 dado_recebido = BitConverter.ToInt32(dados, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Recebi um inteiro de 32 bits: " + dado_recebido.ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Não foi possível processar a mensagem recebida.");
            Console.WriteLine("Motivo: " + ex.Message);
        }

        cliente.Close();
    }
}
```

Espero ter conseguido ajudá-lo.

Comment: ótimo! Muito foda, uma das minhas dúvidas era relacionado a como eu iria converter bytes em outras coisas :D