# Enviar várias variáveis de uma vez socket

Tags: c#, socket

Usando o método [`Socket.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.send(v=vs.110).aspx) teria alguma forma de enviar um pacote com por exemplo um inteiro e uma string de uma só vez?

Eu vi um tal de [Packet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.smartdevice.connectivity.packet(v=vs.90).aspx) que pelo visto era tudo que eu precisava, pois eu posso transformar ele em um array de bytes e depois transformar de volta em packet mas não consegui usar a namespace `Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity`, é como se ela não existisse na vinha versão do .NET. Mas contudo, alguém tem uma solução melhor que essa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ícaro, de acordo com a resposta dada nesta pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149582/e-se-eu-quiser-enviar-e-receber-um-pacote):

Sim, é possível.
Basta você saber o tamanho em bytes do seu conteúdo. 
Sendo assim imagine que você enviou um inteiro de 32 bits e uma string contendo 10 bytes, respectivamente através de um socket.

Editado (Adicionando método para transformação dos objetos em array de bytes):

Quem envia o conteúdo deve gerar os bytes a serem enviados da seguinte forma (como exemplo):

```
Int32 codigo = 123;
String conteudo = "teste123";

const int buffer_length = 1024;
byte[] dados = new byte[buffer_length];

dados = BitConverter.GetBytes(codigo);
Buffer.BlockCopy(conteudo.ToCharArray(), 0, dados, dados.Length, conteudo.Length);
```

Quem recebe deverá ler da seguinte forma (considerando ausência de espaços ou quaisquer outros caracteres dentre os bytes enviados):

```
//Declara-se o buffer de recebimento de dados
const int buffer_length = 1024;
byte[] dados = new byte[buffer_length];

//Recebe-se os dados da socket cliente
int recv_length = cliente.Receive(dados, buffer_length, SocketFlags.None);

//Contador para controle de "Em qual byte paramos a leitura?"
int byte_inicial = 0;

//Recebemos o inteiro através de um array de bytes e convertemos ele.
Int32 inteiro_recebido = BitConverter.ToInt32(dados, 0);
//Logo acrescemos o seu tamanho em bytes ao total de bytes lido
byte_inicial += sizeof(Int32);

//Declaramos um buffer isolado para a string que vem a seguir
byte[] bytes_str_recebida = new byte[buffer_length];
//E copiamos ela no array de bytes recém declarado passando os parâmetros que 
// indicam onde no array original a string está e qual seu tamanho
Buffer.BlockCopy(dados, byte_inicial, bytes_str_recebida, 0, dados.Length - byte_inicial);

//E finalmente convertemos os bytes correspondentes ao texto recebido para o tipo String.
string str_recebida = bytes_str_recebida.ToString();
```

Deixei bem comentado o código (completo na pergunta linkada) para que fique mais fácil entender.

Para adicionar outros tipos ao conteúdo é o mesmo esquema, basta saber onde o conteúdo está e qual seu tamanho em bytes.

Espero ter conseguido auxiliar.

Comment: Eu tinha feito algo bem parecido ontem, mas tava dando um erro muito tosco, vou postar aqui nos comentários pra você ver

Comment: Tentei da seguinte forma: http://pastebin.com/2iwdkqjF, porém está dando erro na linha que eu mando a quantidade de bytes da mensagem

Comment: cara, os parametros  das suas utilizações de BitConverter estão incorretos, por isso o problema. Dá uma lida melhor no código ai em cima, o GetBytes recebe por parametro o objeto que ele vai ler e transformar em bytes.

Comment: Mas logicamente, na linha que da erro eu envio os bytes representando o tamanho dos bytes da string, entendeu?

Comment: Resolvido... Eu estava utilizando `bufferOfClient = BitConverter.GetBytes(0)` nesse caso o tamanho da array se limitava automaticamente ao tamanho do 0 em bytes :/

Comment: Ótimo, que bom que conseguiu. Mudanças aparentemente insignificantes no início do código normalmente impactam no código que segue negativamente...